# Puppeteer does not evaluate web-app on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, puppeteer, telegram

I'm using puppeteer on my telegram bot to fetch stuff from the web.
Locally, it's all work just fine, but here is the catch:

When trying to fetch the URL's HTML, the given response is not the HTML file, but the web app with all the js files. On my local machine  - I'm getting the HTML file with all needed links.

That's my code:

```js
return await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
  headless: true,
}).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

  await page.goto(targetUrl)

  await page.waitForTimeout(2000)
  const data = await page.$$eval(SELECTORS, (res) => {
      return res.map(r => {
        return r.getAttribute('ATRR')
      })
    }) as never as string[]

    .......
})
```

PS --------------
already added this repo to Heroku:

```
https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when you are using `puppeteer-extra`, you need to install `puppeteer` library too.

For some reason, they both depend BUT not auto-installed, so the Chromium engine didn't install on Heroku, and it does explain how it does on my local machine - which has it by default.